# Calling an APEX method from a different class

Tags: apex, class

I have a method in one class, but I need to move it out to another class.

I'm aware this question has been asked several times already, but I'm getting an error I don't understand.

How can I call a method from a different class?

Like so:

```
global with sharing class FirstController extends ThirdController{

    public List<Task> getListOfObjects() {

        SecondController sc = new SecondController();

        return sc.getAllObjects();  
    }
}


global with sharing class SecondController{

    public List<Task> getAllObjects() {

        List<Task> myObjects; =
          ( 
            //LOGIC
          );

          return myObjects;
    }
}
```

I get the follwoing error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SecondController].getAllObjects() FirstController.cls
```

Is there a mistake somewhere I can't see?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and am able save the class and make a call to the method in the FirstController which subsequently calls the SecondController.

```
global with sharing class SecondController{
    public List<Task> getAllObjects() {
        return null;
    }
}

global with sharing class FirstController {
    public List<Task> getListOfObjects() {
        SecondController sc = new SecondController();
        return sc.getAllObjects();  
    }
}
```

I am not sure what your ThirdController class was so I took it out from my code.

This works just perfectly.